# add padding-top to the entire jQuery Mobile page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, padding

I'm looking to add a `padding-top` of `20px` to my entire jQuery Mobile page. (a `data-role="header" data-position="fixed"` element is at the top of the page). How can I accomplish this?

```
body{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Whst´s about this one here?

```
.ui-page {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

This one`s better?

```
.ui-content {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't lower the header

Comment: So the new solution lowers everything except the header, probably because it is `data-position="fixed"`

Comment: `.ui-content, #header {
    margin-top: 20px;
}` seems to work, now I just need to change the background color for where the margin is.

Comment: That should be the ".ui-page"

Comment: `.ui-page{
    background-color: green !important;
}` doesn't work.

Comment: try this: .ui-page {background: lime;}

Comment: with the chrome dev tools or firebug you can easy inspect styles!

Comment: So that does change the color, however I only want the background color changed where the new margin is. This may not be "easily" possible and that's all right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41901/discussion-between-chris--and-hope4you)